# Deploy fails from TFS to Azure

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-web-app-service

I've been trying to deploy my website directly to my development slot on Azure (Web App). Solution builds fine but seems like it's failing somehow when the agent tries to drop the package on Azure Web App. Unafortunately there's no more details, that what I got (subscription name and id masked for obvious reason):

```
******************************************************************************
Starting: Azure Deployment: webapp
******************************************************************************
Import-Module -Name C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\ServiceManagement\Azure\Azure.psd1 -Global
Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName ****** -SubscriptionId ****** -Certificate ******** -Environment AzureCloud
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionId ******
Finding C:\a\1\a\**\*.zip
packageFile= C:\a\1\a\webapp.zip
Get-AzureWebSite -Name webapp -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable azureWebSiteError -Slot dev
WebSite 'webapp(dev)' found.
Publish-AzureWebsiteProject -Name "webapp" -Package "C:\a\1\a\webapp.zip" -Slot "dev"  -ErrorVariable publishAzureWebsiteError
(9/15/2016 7:04:04 PM) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.
******************************************************************************
Finishing: Azure Deployment: webapp
******************************************************************************
```

Comment: As a test, does it also fail if you try deploying directly from your local machine instead of from VSTS?

Comment: Nope, it works perfectly! :)

Comment: Then it might be some issue on the VSTS side. Sorry, not my area :)

Comment: Could you add the detail info of the related build task?

Comment: Patrick thats all the info that I got from output :\

Comment: Sorry for the later reply, I didn't make it clear. I mean what's the detail build step(task) are you using in your build definition? Are you using [this one](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/build/steps/deploy/azure-web-app-deployment)? And what's the detail configuration of your step are you using? You can also take a look at this tutorial from MSDN [**Deploying an Azure Web Site using the new build system in Visual Studio Online**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/06/12/deploying-an-azure-web-site-using-the-new-build-system-in-visual-studio-online/)